# Displaying the number of orders by status in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

have a good time
I wanted to display the number of orders by status on the customer account page of my WordPress site, in such a way that the number of completed orders, canceled orders, and orders in progress are calculated separately and displayed through a shortcode.
I tried the below but I have not received a response
Thank you for your advice

```php
function display_woocommerce_order_count( $atts, $content = null ) {

    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'status' => 'completed',
    ), $atts );

    $statuses    = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $args['status'] ) );
    $order_count = 0;

    foreach ( $statuses as $status ) {

        // if we didn't get a wc- prefix, add one
        if ( 0 !== strpos( $status, 'wc-' ) ) {
            $status = 'wc-' . $status;
        }

        $order_count += wp_count_posts( 'shop_order' )->$status;
    }

    ob_start();

    echo number_format( $order_count );

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'wc_order_count', 'display_woocommerce_order_count' );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get processing status orders count in WooCommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681198/get-processing-status-orders-count-in-woocommerce)

Comment: After a lot of research, I came to the conclusion with this code.
```php
function get_completed_orders_count() {
    // Get the current user ID
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Query the completed orders for the current user
    $completed_orders = wc_get_orders(array(
        'status'    => 'completed',
        'customer'  => $user_id,
        'limit'     => -1, // -1 indicates no limit
    ));

    return count($completed_orders);
}
add_shortcode( 'completed_orders_count', 'get_completed_orders_count' );
```